# What is the answer to this question about aircraft position based on an NDB?

Tags: radio-navigation

> An aircraft is intending to track from NDB ‘A’ to NDB ‘B’ on a track
>   of 050° (T), heading 060° (T). If the RBI shows the relative bearing
>   of ‘A’ to be 180° and the relative bearing of ‘B’ to be 330° then the
>   aircraft is:
>
> - A. Port of track and nearer ‘A’
> - B. Port of track and nearer ‘B’
> - C. Starboard of track and nearer ‘A’
> - D. Starboard of track and nearer ‘B’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way: the plane's heading is known, but the plane's actual track is not. Also the bearing from A to B is known-- it is the intended track.

Bearing from point A to plane = reciprocal of 60 + 180 = reciprocal of 240 = 60.

Bearing from point B to plane = reciprocal of 60 +330  = reciprocal of 390 = reciprocal of 030 = 210

Draw a sketch of A and B, with B 50 degrees from A.  Draw the bearings from A and B to the plane-- the plane is located where these bearing lines cross-- and it will be clear that the plane is right of the intended track, and closer to B than A.

See diagram in other answer!

Whichever corner of the triangle is the larger angle--  the corner by point A or the corner by point B-- must correspond to the waypoint that is closest to the plane.

Comment: Thanks alot , when comparing both answers the problem becomes very easy.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, "D" is correct. A picture is worth a thousand words......

[image]